# Name of old, animated kid's film from back in the late 70s, early 80s about a falling star, placed as headlight in car

Tags: story-identification, movie, stop-motion-animation

I'm looking for the name of an old children's film I watched back in school in the late 70s, early 80s.
The style of the movie was what got me: it was a stop motion film, but drawn in crayon, taking children's crayon drawings, and using those scenes in the movie.
I don't remember the entire plot, but certain scenes/ideas come to mind:

- A falling star comes down to someone I believe named 'Alexander', who places it as a headlight on his car.
- He then drives his car on a wild ride across the world.
- There's even a scene where he rides a giant whale with it to another land.
- The narrator, I think, is a child.

Again, this was one of those films they'd show us kids during breaks in first grade or so.  And this was a from a projector, not a video from a VCR.